# Crystal Reports Printing blank tag with redirected thermal printer

Tags: crystal-reports, zebra-printers

I have the following scenario:

- ERP Server in the Cloud
- Every machine post connects to server in the cloud by Microsoft Remote Desktop
- A Zebra thermal printer connected to one of the machine by USB
- A file with the report configurated by Crystal Reports

Problems:
When i connect to remote desktop the RD delivers a different number of redirected printer to the Zebra printer.
When i print from the ERP with the redirected printer saved on the report it prints well. But in the next day it delivers another number of redirection and when i print again it delivers a blank report.

How i can solve it?

I tried not to save the printer in the report and it delivers blank.

I expect a way that i can print all of the time.

Comment: Is installing the printer on the server an option?  The number you are finding in the printer name represents the RDS Session the user was given when they connect, so this number can be different each time you reconnect.

Comment: For the time i can't figure out how i install the printer in the server because the server is in a cloud supplier. It can't recognize the printer installation on the physical PC even if i share it.

Comment: You may need to reach out to your cloud services provider for help with this.  There is usually a cloud printing service that is needed to connect local network printers to cloud based environments.